# Read serial port with inter-character timeout for long streams

Tags: c, unix, serial-port, uart

in my application i am connected to serial device which will send periodic data whose size is unknown. I do not want to detect incoming frame using StartofFrame and EndOfFrame keywords. Instead of this, i want to detect incoming frame using inter-character timeout. There always will be some duration between incoming data frames at least 100ms. 
So, i can detect frames using this time interval. I am opening serial port using this function:

```
uint8_t open_serial_port(uart_device* dev)
{
    dev->fd = open(dev->path, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (dev->fd < 0)
    {
    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Serial Port {%s}-{%s} couldn't opened", dev->name, dev->path);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Serial Port {%s}-{%s} opened with fd {%d}", dev->name, dev->path, dev->fd);

    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(dev->fd, &tty) < 0)
    {
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Serial Connection attributes get for fd {%d} failed with errno cause {%s}", dev->fd, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cfmakeraw(&tty);
    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t) dev->speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t) dev->speed);

    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 255;   //! This is used to block to get at least VMIN characters
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;  //! used to block for tens of seconds timeout 10 -> 1 seconds timeout

    tty.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; //! Mask the character size bits
    tty.c_cflag |= get_start_stop_opt(dev->data, dev->stop);    //! Set data, stop bits
    tty.c_cflag |= get_parity_opt(dev->parity); //! set parity configuration
    tty.c_cflag |= get_hw_flow_control(dev->flow_control);

    if (tcsetattr(dev->fd, TCSANOW, &tty))
    {
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Serial Connection attributes set for fd {%d} failed with errno cause {%s}", dev->fd, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Serial Connection {%s}-{%s} established. speed: %d, parity: %s, data: %d, stop: %d, flw_ctrl: %d", dev->name, dev->path, dev->speed,
    dev->parity, dev->data, dev->stop, dev->flow_control);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am reading serial port in blocking mode:

```
    readSize = read(dev->fd, &buf, UART_MAX_PAYLOAD);
    if (readSize < 0)
    {
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, "UART Read failed while reading {%s}, error {%s}", dev->path, strerror(errno));
        usleep(1000 * 1000);
        continue;
    }

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Uart read completed. readSize: %d", readSize);
```

Actually VMIN and VTIME parameters of termios is suitable for my situation but VMIN and VTIME is defined as 8 bit. So, i can state maximum of 255 characters to read. 
So, when device sends 2048 bytes of data, i read this as :

```
Uart read completed. readSize: 496
Uart read completed. readSize: 496
Uart read completed. readSize: 496
Uart read completed. readSize: 496
Uart read completed. readSize: 64
```

Somehow, i can not read whole data at same time.

What is the problem about reading large data in blocking mode? How can i read large serial data in one time?

Best regards.

Comment: Technically the VMIN and VTIME specifications are being met, so what you're getting could be the way it is.  The actual "max" read size (496 in your test, only 262 in my test) is probably dependent on the UART driver and DMA implementation.  FYI your program accesses a serial terminal, and not a *"serial port'*.  There are numerous buffers the received data has to go through: the driver's DMA buffer, the tty flip buffer, and termios buffer.

Comment: Your program does have some bugs (as well as being posted incomplete, e.g. missing numerous declarations and definitions).  Your termios initialization of `... |= get...`  will not work in all cases.  If the attribute is already enabled, this code cannot clear that flag.  You fail to ensure that the CREAD flag is enabled.  The 2nd argument of **read()** is incorrectly the address of the address of the array.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you for your warnings about code, you are right about bugs. I did not find any solution to my problem. So i decide to get bytes separately and 496, 496, ... etc. using select() and combine them until a timeout occurs. So, i will get whole packet.